# Find length of array of functions in Julia

Tags: vector, julia

I want to find the length, nc, of this "vector of functions". I should be 2.

```
comp(x) = [([x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8],x[9], x[10]], tmp(x)) ; ([x[1],x[2]], [x[3],x[4]])];
nc = ....
```

I tried with `length(comp)` and `length(comp(x))` but it doesn't work. I get `"x not defined"` and  `"no method matching length(::typeof(comp))"`, respectively.

Comment: your `comp` is not a vector of functions but a function. Probably this is the reason of your problem.

Comment: Thank you! But I still want the length though

Comment: You haven't defined the `tmp` function, so it's difficult to answer confidently. But `length(comp(x))` should work as long as you define `x` beforehand.

Comment: tmp(x) = [x[3] + 10; -x[3] + 20; x[4] + 10; -x[4] + 20; x[1] -  2*x[3] - 10; x[2] - 2*x[4] - 10] I am going to solve an optimisation problem. So x is not defined beforehand

Comment: Well, you must have some `x` to call `comp` with. How else can you calculate the length of the output of the `comp` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling together some of the comments to hopefully make things clearer:

What you have written is essentially

```
function comp(x)
    a = [x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8],x[9], x[10]]
    b = [x[1],x[2]]
    c = [x[3],x[4]]
    return [(a, tmp(x)); (b, c)]
end
```

that is, you have defined a function `comp` which takes one argument `x` and then returns a 2-element vector of 2-element tuples, with the first tuple holding values 5 to 10 of `x` and the result of `tmp(x)` (this function is not defined in your code so we don't know what it returns), and the second tuple holding the first and second, and third and fourth elements of `x`, respectively.

To illustrate, assume `tmp(x)` just sums up the elements of `x`, then we can pass some array (in the below example a range) of numbers to `comp` and see it in action:

```
julia> tmp(x) = sum(x)
tmp (generic function with 1 method)

julia> comp(1:20)
2-element Vector{Tuple{Vector{Int64}, Any}}:
 ([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 210)
 ([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

and you can get the result of the return value:

```
julia> length(comp(1:20))
2
```